# Stopwatch (with timer function) that was implemented in an app using Flutter paused when the app is put to background mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background

I was trying to implement a stopwatch feature in a mobile app using Flutter, and I followed some other people's suggestion to use "isolate" to make the timer work in the background mode, and the timer works great when the app is open in the front, however, I found the timer stopped running whenever I put the app in the background mode, for example, when I clicked on the big button at the bottom of my iPhone 8 and open another app, and then I found the timer basically paused and only resumed the counting when I brought the app back to front...my sample code is as below.

Thanks for the comments to suggest using workaround to make calculate the time instead of counting in the background, and sorry for the confusion - I guess my real questions are, why “isolate” is not working for background process as flutter document suggests, what I did wrong and what is the best way to make a process such as a timer to work in the background. This timer application is jus an example.

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {

  runApp(MyApp());

}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(

      home: MyHomePage(),

    );

  }

}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override

  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Isolate? isolate;

  ReceivePort? receivePort;

  static int val = 0;


  @override

  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    spawnNewIsolate();

  }


  void spawnNewIsolate() async {

    receivePort = ReceivePort();

    try {

      isolate = await Isolate.spawn(stopWatch, receivePort!.sendPort);

      
      receivePort!.listen((dynamic message) {

        setState(() {
          print('New message from Isolate: $message');
          val = int.parse(message);
        });

      });

    } catch (e) {

      print("Error: $e");

    }

  }


  //spawn accepts only static methods or top-level functions

  static void stopWatch(SendPort sendPort) {

    Duration timerInterval = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer? timer = Timer.periodic(timerInterval, (_)  {
      val++;
      print('val:' + val.toString());
      sendPort.send(val.toString());
    });

  }


  @override

  void dispose() {

    super.dispose();

    receivePort!.close();

    isolate!.kill();

  }


  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("Isolate Demo"),

      ),

      body: Center(
        child:
        Text('timer:' + val.toString()),
        )
    );

  }

}
```

Comment: Don't count. Take a `Date` when you start and then determine elapsed time from that.

Comment: Paulw11 is right: just save start `DateTime` somewhere (for example in shared prefs) and every time you start your app you can compute the elapsed time as a difference of `DateTime.now()` and saved starting `DateTime`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it may work in this case, however, I guess at this point, I’m more interested in why “isolate” doesn’t work in the background mode as flutter documents suggest and what is the best way to make a process such as a timer to work in the background, other than a workaround. Sorry for the confusion. I will modify my question.

Comment: Timers (and execution in general) do not continue when you leave the app. Apps are suspended when you leave them. (If they kept running, our batteries would be exhausted far more quickly!) That's one of the reasons why you use the start date for the stopwatch, so that the fact that you can have your stopwatch appear to continue from where it should be, even though the timer wasn't actually firing while the app was suspended.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I understand the concerns with battery usage, and I guess my question was not well asked - what I want to know is, what if we do need to run something in background, for example, uploading a big video file while I may switch to another app to talk to my friend in a chat…of course when I design background process I have to make sure it wouldn’t drain the battery.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusions, let me make my question simple -would using separate “isolate” in flutter make execution keep running in the background while the user switch to another app? Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: For iOS, there are all sorts of special, legitimate background tasks that Apple has designed nice, power-efficient solutions. E.g., if downloading a large file in the background in iOS, we use a background `URLSessionConfiguration` for our `URLSession`. When you do that, your download is passed to a background daemon that does the download for you. See [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/). But your app isn’t running in the background. The daemon does the download for you.

Comment: Or perhaps you just need 30 seconds or less to finish something in the background, then Apple [provides a mechanism for that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask). Or for background fetch and background utility tasks, Apple provides [Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks). Maybe [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063/) video would be helpful primer on these issues.

Comment: I appreciated your answers @Rob, however, my questions is about using “isolate” in flutter, instead of iOS native app development. I want to know why “isolate” doesn’t work in background execution and what is the best way to do it if it’s not using “isolate”

Comment: Understood, and no offense intended. My point was merely that the iOS ecosystem simply doesn’t permit generalized, unconstrained, background execution (except for very limited cases like VOIP, navigation, music, apps not in App Store, etc.) and there’s nothing that you can do in flutter to get around this limitation. If you have a specific use-case (e.g. background uploads), then I’d suggest you focus on how to achieve that. But if you’re hoping that “isolate” is somehow going to get around the rules of the operating system, that’s unlikely to be a fruitful exercise. Good luck!